# Getting Unrecognized option: --topic while executing ReadFromKafka.java

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am getting below error while executing `ReadFromKafka.java`

The source is available in https://github.com/dataArtisans/kafka-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/ReadFromKafka.java

> Unrecognized option: --topic Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have provided the following arguments :

```
--topic test --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --zookeeper.connect localhost:2181 --group.id myGroup
```

I followed the the steps as given by 
http://data-artisans.com/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to/

Thanks in Advance

~SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to start the example? From an IDE?

If so, are you sure you've put the arguments into the "program arguments" section, not into the JVM arguments?

Comment: Great. Can you mark my answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with calling your jar.

Try something like this

java -jar myjar.jar "--topic test --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --zookeeper.connect localhost:2181 --group.id myGroup"

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me because there were no valid jar files that contained the kafka code. Since no valid jars were found, the CLASS_PATH variable is empty in `bin/kafka-run-class.sh`. That shell script should probably check for that condition and return a better error, instead, it just leaves an invalid `-cp` flag in the `java` command it is assembling. This causes the error message you (we) are seeing where it spits out java usage info (because `-cp` without anything following it is invalid).

The solution for me was to build the kafka source using `gradlew jar`.

The root of this issue is that the documentation expects you to be running from an actual kafka install, rather than from the src directory.